# Insert Value based on One Column based on Value on another Column

Tags: mysql

I just tried to set `_timeStamp` column to store value on the basis of `HOUR` of `_date` column and tried to create table as like below but encounter 1064 error. I'm new to mysql so help me in figuring out mine mistake.

```
create table `help` (`_ID` integer not null,
`_date` datetime not null,
`_timeStamp` integer not null 
        SET  (1 if HOUR(`_date`)<10 else 2 if HOUR(`_date`)<16 else 3 if HOUR(`_date`)<24
            else -1),
PRIMARY KEY (`_ID`) 
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to create a computed column and I am pretty sure MySQL does not support them. There are a few ways around this issue:

- Do the computation in the logic that inserts the data
- Create a trigger on the table to do the calculation when data is inserted/updated
- Create a view to represent the data how you want it.

My personal preference would be to use a view as it is easier to maintain as is a much neater solution. Your view would look something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW `vwHelp`
AS
SELECT `_ID`, `_date`,
CASE
   WHEN HOUR(`_date`) <10 THEN 1
   WHEN HOUR(`_date`) <16 THEN 2
   WHEN HOUR(`_date`) <24 THEN 3
   ELSE -1
END AS `_timestamp`
FROM `help`;
```